# Pandas dataframe to Json transform - pythonic way

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am bit rusty in pandas to json transforms.
I have a pandas data frame like this for a fictional library:

| userId | visitId | readingTime | Books | BookType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | 1 | 300 | book1,book2,book3 | Fiction |
| u2 | 1 | 400 | book4,book5 | Horror |
| u2 | 2 | 250 | book6 | Romance |

Need to create a json that is like:

```json
{
  "visitSummary": {
    "u1": [
      {
        "readingTime": 300,
        "Books": [
          "book1",
          "book2",
          "book3"
        ],
        "BookType": "Fiction"
      }
    ],
    "u2": [
      {
        "readingTime": 400,
        "Books": [
          "book4",
          "book5"
        ],
        "BookType": "Horror"
      },
      {
        "readingTime": 250,
        "Books": [
          "book6"
        ],
        "BookType": "Romance"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I was thinking to do it using nested loops and processing each row. I am hoping, there is a simpler pythonic way to do it.

Using Python 3.10 and pandas 2.1.4

Comment: Can you create a copy-pastable form of the DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do that but stack overflow threw a fit. Let me see if I can do it here:    
   userid  visitid  readingTime  Books                        BookType      
        u1       1      300               book1,book2,book3   Fiction
        u2       1      400                book4,book5             Horror
        u2       2     250                 book6                        Romance

Comment: Is `Books` a comma separated list string?

Comment: Yes, Books are a comma separated string

Comment: @Broken You can copy the table then use `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')`. Or pop it into a [`StringIO`](//docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) and use `read_csv(..., sep='\t')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) & [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) :

```
out = {
    "visitSummary":
    (df.assign(Books=df["Books"].str.split(","))
       .groupby("userId").apply(lambda g: g.drop(
         columns=["userId", "visitId"]).to_dict("records")).to_dict())
}
```

Output :

```
import json; print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))
{
    "visitSummary": {
        "u1": [
            {
                "readingTime": 300,
                "Books": [
                    "book1",
                    "book2",
                    "book3"
                ],
                "BookType": "Fiction"
            }
        ],
        "u2": [
            {
                "readingTime": 400,
                "Books": [
                    "book4",
                    "book5"
                ],
                "BookType": "Horror"
            },
            {
                "readingTime": 250,
                "Books": [
                    "book6"
                ],
                "BookType": "Romance"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out. I haven't tested all answers for my use case. But This one by Timeless worked in 1st try. Happy New year everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested loops, just one loop would do. Here's one way to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Assuming this is your DataFrame
data = {
    'userId': ['u1', 'u2', 'u2'],
    'visitId': [1, 1, 2],
    'readingTime': [300, 400, 250],
    'Books': ['book1,book2,book3', 'book4,book5', 'book6'],
    'BookType': ['Fiction', 'Horror', 'Romance']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

json_data = {}
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    user_id = row['userId']
    if user_id not in json_data:
        json_data[user_id] = []

    books = row['Books'].split(',')
    visit_data = {
        'readingTime': row['readingTime'],
        'Books': books,
        'BookType': row['BookType']
    }
    json_data[user_id].append(visit_data)

# Wrap the data with your main key
final_json = {'visitSummary': json_data}

with open('output.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(final_json, json_file, indent=2)
```

Output:

```
{
  "visitSummary": {
    "u1": [
      {
        "readingTime": 300,
        "Books": [
          "book1",
          "book2",
          "book3"
        ],
        "BookType": "Fiction"
      }
    ],
    "u2": [
      {
        "readingTime": 400,
        "Books": [
          "book4",
          "book5"
        ],
        "BookType": "Horror"
      },
      {
        "readingTime": 250,
        "Books": [
          "book6"
        ],
        "BookType": "Romance"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import json

# if values in Books are strings:
df["Books"] = df["Books"].str.split(",")

out = {}
for user_id, group in df.groupby("userId"):
    out[user_id] = []
    for reading_time, books, book_type in zip(
        group["readingTime"], group["Books"], group["BookType"]
    ):
        out[user_id].append(
            {"readingTime": reading_time, "Books": books, "BookType": book_type}
        )

out = {"visitSummary": out}
print(out)


with open("data.json", "w") as f_out:
    json.dump(out, f_out, indent=4)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "visitSummary": {
        "u1": [
            {
                "readingTime": 300,
                "Books": ["book1", "book2", "book3"],
                "BookType": "Fiction",
            }
        ],
        "u2": [
            {"readingTime": 400, "Books": ["book4", "book5"], "BookType": "Horror"},
            {"readingTime": 250, "Books": ["book6"], "BookType": "Romance"},
        ],
    }
}
```

and saves `data.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Split the Books column into a list of strings using `Series.str.split()`. You can then use `.groupby()`, `.apply()` and `.to_json()` to get the desired output:

```py
df["Books"] = df["Books"].str.split(",")
groupby_func = lambda x: json.loads(x.drop(["userId", "visitId"], axis=1).to_json(orient="records", index=False)
groupby_result = df.groupby("userId").apply(groupby_func)).to_json(orient="index")
{"visitSummary": json.loads(groupby_result)}
```

This outputs:

```json
{
    "visitSummary": {
        "u1": [
            {
                "readingTime": "300",
                "Books": [
                    "book1",
                    "book2",
                    "book3"
                ],
                "BookType": "Fiction"
            }
        ],
        "u2": [
            {
                "readingTime": "400",
                "Books": [
                    "book4",
                    "book5"
                ],
                "BookType": "Horror"
            },
            {
                "readingTime": "250",
                "Books": [
                    "book6"
                ],
                "BookType": "Romance"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```